# Utilize C# 8 indices and ranges

Tags: c#, indexing, indices

I am trying to solve an online challenge in an efficient way. I have to basically output a string in a certain format given an array of `int`.

I have to make the string look like : `(123) 456-7890` (the input array is guaranteed to be correct length).

I found out about the new C# indices and ranges and tried something like this:

```
public static string GenerateOutput(int[] numbers)
{
    return $"({numbers[0..2]}) {numbers[3..5]}-{numbers[6..9]}";
}
```

But that doesn't return the desired result. How can I transform them to strings and return the correct output?

Comment: So these numbers in the array - can they have values like -38787123? What is the defined range for them?

Comment: @MatthewWatson No, the array with contain 10 integers with values 0 to 9.

Comment: You can transform all the numbers to strings to use indices and formatting (`numbers.Select(i => i.ToString())`), but the resulting solution will not be efficient. An efficient solution will be a long-winded but obvious one that minimizes allocations (e.g. `Span<char> s = stackalloc char["(000) 000-0000".Length]; s[0] = '('; s[1] = (char) (numbers[0] + '0'); ... return s.ToString();` -- `new StringBuilder("(000) 000-0000")` if you don't feel like getting overly fancy with `Span`). Of course, worth keeping in mind is that premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you're putting in arrays inside the string.  `ToString()` on an array will result a string describing the type, not a string of its values.  You need to concatenate those arrays.  You can create a local function to make it more convenient to use:

```
string getNums (int start, int end) =>
    string.Join("", numbers[start..end]);
```

Outside of that, your indexing is inclusive on both ends.  But according to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes):

> A range specifies the start and end of a range. Ranges are exclusive, meaning the end isn't included in the range.

That's not what exclusive means.  [c-sharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-ranges-and-indices-in-c-sharp-8-0/) puts it better:

> The Range operator .. specifies the start (Inclusive) and end (exclusive) of a range.

I imagine they had a reason for this, but it is a very surprising choice from my perspective.

Regardless, with this in mind, you can implement the local function like this:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };

string getNums (int start, int end) =>
    string.Join("", numbers[start..end]);

return $"({getNums(0,3)}) {getNums(3,6)}-{getNums(6,10)}";
```

Comment: The choice of inclusive start and exclusive end corresponds to indexes counting the insertion points between characters and not the characters themselves.

Comment: @BenVoigt, can you elaborate on that?  What's the advantage of considering points between elements over the (at least to me) more intuitive consideration of element position.

Comment: Well, it is necessary to work with points between elements for certain things (specifying insertion point, cursor position, etc) and for the rest it doesn't really harm anything.  It's also more natural for GetTextExtents to tell you the location of the edge following the substring, rather than the location (center? center of baseline? bounds?) of the last character.  And for hit testing, you need to compare to boundaries between characters, not centers of characters. And of course, it makes the length of a range equal to (end - start) instead of (end - start + 1).  Empty ranges are nicer too.

Comment: @pwilcox Half open intervals are the norm for ranges. They have a number of advantages, but an important one is that it makes it easy to represent an empty range.

Answer (score 3):

It'd be a lot more useful if your numbers were a string so they could be ranged directly:

```
var s = string.Join("", numbers);
```

Now you can cut your string up using ranges:

```
var ph = $"(s[..3]}) {s[3..6]}-{s[^4..]}";
```